# How to know if an audio unit of type AudioFilePlayer is playing (rendering)

Tags: cocoa, core-audio

I use an AUGraph and it contains some audio units of subtype `kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer`.

I know we can ask if the AUGraph is running thanks to `AUGraphIsRunning` but I would like to know if an AudioFilePlayer audio unit is currently playing the AudioFileID i.e "produce" sound. I don't see any function like this.

Indeed the graph could "running" but the AudioFilePlayer audio unit could not produce sound (because of: end of audio file, pause, and so on...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ones who are also looking for a solution, the only fix I found is to use a bool variable `is_playing`. Apparently, An audioFilePlayer doesn't allow to access this kind of property...